# Decrypt openssl AES with CryptoJS

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, cryptojs

I'm trying to decrypt a file encrypted with openssl using [CryptoJS 3.1.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js).

Everything works fine if I encrypt and decrypt using CryptoJS, same goes for OpenSSL in shell, but when I try to mix CryptoJS with OpenSSL everything goes wrong.

The file is created using this command:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in file.txt -out file.enc -k password
```

and I try to decrypt like this:

```js
fs.readFile('file.enc', function(err, data) {
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
                    data.toString(),
                    "password",
                    { mode : CryptoJS.mode.CBC }
                  );

  console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
});

// Give me this err: Uncaught Error: Malformed UTF-8 data
```

And in the other way, I do :

```js
fs.readFile('file.txt', function(err, data) {
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
                    data.toString(),
                    "password",
                    { mode : CryptoJS.mode.CBC });

  fs.writeFile('file.enc', encrypted);
});
```

And then in Shell:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in file.enc -out file2.txt -k password
// Give me this err: bad magic number
```

Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: Why are you using CryptoJS in node.js if there is the integrated `crypto` module. Also, which CryptoJS module are you using?

Comment: I require CryptoJS 3.1.5
I encounter similar problem using nodejs crypto module, I can post more sample code if you want.

Comment: sorry, I use this one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not definitely an answer yet but too much for comments:

Commandline `openssl enc` by default uses password-based encryption (PBE) with salt, which means the actual encryption key, and IV when applicable which it is for CBC, are computed from the given password and a random salt value by a [Password Based Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) that makes it more difficult for an adversary to try password-guessing attacks. I don't know your JS module (or much JS at all) but the webpage you link lists a variety of low-level primitives suggesting it does not automatically do PBE. A text string like "password" is (possibly) suitable for PBE, but not direct AES encryption where the key must be exactly 128, 192 or 256 bits and should be random binary data.

If you want openssl's semi-standard **PBE**, match it on the JS side; the item `evpkey` sounds possibly helpful, since `EVP` is the openssl module involved and I know no other (PB)KDF scheme that would be called EVP. If not, the `enc` default PBE is just MD5 of the password concatenated with the salt, iterated with feedback as many times as needed which in this case is three. See https://superuser.com/questions/455463/openssl-hash-function-for-generating-aes-key for an example in (mostly) perl. OpenSSL prefixes the 8 ASCII chars "Salted__" and the 8 bytes of salt to the file, so you need to remove those (and use the salt) before decrypt, or add them after encrypt.

If you want **raw encryption**, choose a more suitable key (on whichever side), and a unique and unpredictable IV unless you always use a new key in which case you can use a fixed IV, and on the openssl side use `-K` (note uppercase) and `-iv` to specify those values *in hex*. See the manpage on any Unix system with openssl installed or https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/enc.html .

Plus in either case `enc` defaults to "PKCS#5" (really PKCS#7) **padding**. I don't know if your JS module does; if not you should specify it. Unless you can guarantee your plaintexts will always be an exact multiple of 16 bytes (after any encoding like UTF8); then you could specify (or maybe default) no padding on the JS side and specify `-nopad` on the openssl side.

Comment: Thank you, that exactly the kind of information I was looking for.
I'll update the main question with my final code when it will work

Comment: CryptoJS actually does PBE in an OpenSSL compatible fashion recreating EVP_BytesToKey. The issue is probably some kind of strange encoding issue, because OP's code should work.

Answer (score 7):

For the record, this is how I decrypt openssl file.

```
//openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in file.txt -out file.enc -k password

fs.readFile('file.enc', function(err, data) {
  var salt          = data.toString("hex", 8, 16),
      enc           = data.toString("hex", 16, data.length),
      derivedParams = CryptoJS.kdf.OpenSSL.execute(
                        password,
                        256/32,
                        128/32,
                        CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt)
                      ),
      cipherParams  = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
                       ciphertext : CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(enc)
                     }),
      decrypted     = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
                        cipherParams,
                        derivedParams.key,
                        { iv : derivedParams.iv }
                      );

  console.log(hex2a(decrypted.toString())); // result is in hexa
});
```

And this is how I encrypt to make it work with OpenSSL

```
fs.readFile('file.txt', function(err, data) {
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data.toString(), password);
      buff      = new Buffer(encrypted.toString(), "base64");

  fs.writeFile('file.enc', buff);
});

// openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in file.enc -out file2.txt -k password
```

Hope it'll help someone :)

Comment: Does this method support the `-salt` option that openssl supports?

Answer (score 2):

This PHP code, which includes command line **OpenSSL** encryption:

http://pastebin.com/sivmZvSw

...is compatible with this **CryptoJS** code, which I normally run on the command line using `jsc` on my Mac:

http://pastebin.com/LcDBG7yj

(This code was written with `CryptoJS` 3.1.2, although I wouldn't expect a major difference between that and 3.1.5.)

The tricks are:

1. As indicated by the other answer, you need to specify the exact key and IV on both sides in order for it to work.
2. Even though AES-256 can theoretically handle 128-bit keys, I have found that only 256-bit keys seem to work.
3. In these examples I have avoided using a salt value. You could arguably make it more secure by including salt, but make sure you specify it correctly in both places.
4. The other thing that catches people out is they think they can just pass a string to the `CryptoJS.decrypt()` function. This is not correct. `CryptoJS.decrypt()` expects a `cipherParams` object. (See example.)
5. Regarding padding: both `CryptoJS` and `OpenSSL` default to PKCS#7, which is functionally equivalent to PKCS#5 except PKCS#7 can handle any block size. When we're talking about 8-byte block sizes, they are identical. Anyway, you shouldn't need to specify the padding in `CrytoJS`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-K 70617373776F7264` instead of `-k password` in the shell command. `70617373776F7264` is the hex code of password.